# Assembler HCS12 how does register with index work with TST-instruction?

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, addressing-mode, indexed, 68hc12

Hello this is my test code:

```
        LDX #$2000
        LDY #$1000
        
        
        LDD #$0000
        
  la:   ADDD #1
        MOVB 1, X+, 1, Y+
        TST -1, X         <-- what do I check here?
        BNE la
```

My question is what do I check with the TST -1,X? I know that TST checks if my register is 0 or negative. But what does -1, X mean?. When is this condition not true?

Comment: What does the manual say about that instruction?

Comment: What do you mean by 'manual'?

Comment: This isn't x86; I don't recognize the ISA.  I think an 8-bit micro where X is a register name, but I don't know which one.  But yeah, every ISA has documentation, read it.  Normally across most ISAs, a `test` or `tst` instruction sets flags according to bitwise-AND, though.

Comment: Looks like 6809.

Comment: Now i understood, its used on the HCS12 board.

Comment: You'll find a HCS12 data sheet [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/HCS12COREUG.pdf). Which seems to say it is a memory operation with the address specified in `X` offset by `-1`

Comment: Aside: you won't get far with microprocessor programming without the data sheet at the very least. Better yet, get a book too. The manufacturers often publish one or more manuals for their device, as well as supplying an assembler, and perhaps a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy function, possibly used for null terminated strings. `X` and `Y` are the 16 bit index registers used to hold addresses.

With `MOVB 1, X+, 1, Y+` you first move the data from address `X` to `Y` and then post-increment both addresses. `TST -1, X` checks the contents of the address that `X` had before that post-increment. If not zero then loop, otherwise stop.